# 'bool' object is not callable that doesn't make sense

Tags: python

The code runs on one pc, but gets an error on another one[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCieP.jpg)

It doesn't make any sense to me, as it is a simple code, I tried to remove parenthesis, but it still didn't work, put more and still. I have some experience on writing on Python, but I can't figure it out on why this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are trying to run as part of your question please?

Comment: maybe the notebook is "poisoned". Have you tried to rerun it in a new environment... or just copy-paste in the python shell?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: the code in the image has no errors. it prints `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only sensible reason for this is that you have assigned some bool value to print, smthng like:

```
print = True
```

Find such string, delete it and then restarting notebook should fix it.

Comment: Possibly in a less obvious way like assigning the result of a comparison or the like.

Comment: Often spelled `print=(foo > 1 and bar > 2)`